# Java ArrayList - deleting elements at Position in Android Exception

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I create some ArrayList with let's say 5 elements. Each element is some object let's say `Recipe` which contains some information about each displayed row at specified `position`. What I try to achive is to delete element at specified `position` from ArrayList using only that position of the element on the screen then `notifyItemRemoved(position)`. Here is my Java Code: [Android Adapter "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457836/android-adapter-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-invalid-index-4-size-is-4)

For example I have displayed:

`[Row 0] Position 0`

`[Row 1] Position 1`

`[Row 2] Position 2`

`[Row 3] Position 3`

`[Row 4] Position 4`

My initial `ArrayList` is like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

When I delete elements like this:

`POSITION = 4`

`list.remove(POSITION);`

`notifyItemRemoved(POSITION);`

After Remove

`[Row 0] Position 0`

`[Row 1] Position 1`

`[Row 2] Position 2`

`[Row 3] Position 3`

`ArrayList` is like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

When delete `POSITION = 3` I have:

`[Row 0] Position 0`

`[Row 1] Position 1`

`[Row 2] Position 2`

`ArrayList` is like this: `[0, 1, 2]`

So everything is fine cause `POSITION` of the deleted element is identical to the position in the `ArrayList`.

But when I do remove some different element f.e.`POSITION = 2` at the begining I have:

`[Row 0] Position 0`

`[Row 1] Position 1`

`[Row 3] Position 3`

`[Row 4] Position 4`

`ArrayList` is like this: `[0, 1, 3, 4]`

When I want now to delete f.e `POSITION = 3` I get something like this:

`[Row 0] Position 0`

`[Row 1] Position 1`

`[Row 3] Position 3`

`ArrayList` is like this: `[0, 1, 3]` - it deletes element after the one I want to delete.

The other thing is that when I try to delete last element with list - `POSITION 4` (at the begining I deleted the element at `POSITION = 2`):

`[Row 0] Position 0`

`[Row 1] Position 1`

`[Row 3] Position 3`

`[Row 4] Position 4`

I get error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4`.

How do I manage to remove elements like this having only position? Is that possbile to do it with ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't understood the concept of the indexing in Arraylist.
when you delete an item from the Arraylist, the indexing of the arraylist is updated.

Check the simple example below and you will get a clear idea about that.

Suppose you arraylist is as shown below:

[Row 0] Position 0

[Row 1] Position 1

[Row 2] Position 2

[Row 3] Position 3

Now, if you remove the item from the Position 1, then the arraylist will be re-indexed accordingly.
So, now the positions in your new list becomes:

[Row 0] Position 0

[Row 2] Position 1

[Row 3] Position 2

Note that the item from the Position 1, i.e: Row 1 has been deleted and the remaining items below Row 1 has been shifted a position 1 above then the previous index.

Now when you delete an item from an arraylist in a loop, then after deleting an item you have to iterate it once more for next deleting or you can use reverse iteration for that.

Let me know if you still need more clarification on this.

Thanks.